# Import PLY doesn't display vertex colors

Tags: import, vertex-colors

I'm trying to import a .PLY mesh in Blender.
I've troubles with colors: the mesh appear in a grayscale palette.
Other softwares open it correctly (eg. MeshLab).

This is the header of the PLY file:

```
ply
format binary_big_endian 1.0
comment created by Geomagic Sculpt Exporter.
element vertex 182488
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
element face 364980
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
```

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: can you link to a small demo .ply file?

Comment: http://156.54.99.175/3d/a.ply

Comment: also see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30314/file-format-with-per-face-colors?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The .PLY importer makes a Vertex Color Layer, if you switch to it you will see the colours.
[image]

And as a cycles material:

[image]