# Showing X3D color per face?

Tags: rendering, materials, vertex-colors

I have an X3D from Meshlab which has color per face, It's a polyhedron where per face colors are the best compared to per vertex.

Can blender show X3D per face colors? I have found an option of per vertex colors in New Material>Options, is viewing per triangle colors not implemented?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30314/file-format-with-per-face-colors?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

related, same thing happens with .ply files: use the Vertex Color layer: [Import PLY doesn't display vertex colors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36783/import-ply-doesnt-display-vertex-colors?lq=1)

In Blender there is no color per polygon, but you can set all vertices of individual polygons to the same color. When vertices are shared by multiple Polygons their vertex_color information is *not*.

If the `.x3d` is formatted correctly, then Blender will make the appropriate `vertex_color` map (tested! for instance with [this file](http://www.web3d.org/x3d-resources/content/examples/Vrml2.0Sourcebook/Chapter16-Color/_pages/page06.html)).

Comment: Thanks alot for the tips, i had a go to find the node arrangement and i lost the materials window i will have another go today.