# Blender 2.81 doesn't seem to be importing vertex color for .ply

Tags: vertex-colors

So people have had similar problems showing colors on .ply files [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36783/import-ply-doesnt-display-vertex-colors) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30314/file-format-with-per-face-colors?rq=1)  but I don't think this is the same case.  I've exported a .ply file from a program called paraview with color info on it.  I've uploaded the file [here](https://skfb.ly/6OKUo) and as you can see, the color info came with it.

But for whatever reason when I import it into blender and go look for the per-vertex color info where I would expect to find it, its empty:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong?  It seems like there had been a problem with impo[rting .ply color for a bit in 2.80,](https://developer.blender.org/T63227) but this is 2.81.  I would assume it was fixed?

Comment: Downloading requires an account, therefore I haven't tested it yet, but by the looks of it it's only vertices and no faces correct?

Comment: I believe so, think its no faces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender's ply importer only adds vertex colors when they are part of a face or triangle strip. You can see this in the source code of [`import_ply.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_mesh_ply/import_ply.py$228).

`mesh_colors` is the list that collects the vertex colors. The assignment of values to `mesh_colors` and the indices to `mesh_faces` happens in the `add_face()` function. This function is only called when a `b'face'` or `b'tristrips'` is encountered in the ply object. Only when `mesh_faces` is not empty and the required color channels are present the new set of vertex colors is created through `mesh.vertex_colors.new()`. Therefore vertex colors are only imported if the colored vertices were part of a face.

Comment: Is there a way to get the colors for just points?  Or am I out of luck?

Comment: You could try add-ons. I haven't tested it, but this one is supposed to work with .ply point clouds: https://github.com/uhlik/bpy

Answer (score 1):

You can set the material to use vertex color in the *Node Editor* or by selecting it from *Surface > Base Color*.

Make sure your view is in *Material Preview* or Render mode (<kbd>Z</kbd>  for shortcut) to see the changes.

[image: Set Vertex Color]