# Import .ply with vertex colors into Blender

Tags: vertex-colors, point-clouds

I'm trying to render something that would look like this:
[image]

I've had a similar problem here: [Blender 2.81 doesn't seem to be importing vertex color for .ply](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158052/blender-2-81-doesnt-seem-to-be-importing-vertex-color-for-ply)

And in that question I linked where other people had similar problems.  I've attempted to use the "Point Cloud Visualizer" linked in one of the comments to figure this out, and that's where I'm currently stuck.

I have a .ply file is exported from 3DSlicer.  Here is a comment thread explaining why they use .ply and per-vertex color attributes: https://discourse.slicer.org/t/tractography-export-by-color/3191

I'm trying to import that point cloud into Blender using the point cloud visualizer and I am following this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXct_7k779Q to use the Point Cloud Visualizer to bring in the .ply,  and that addon installs correctly and everything.  When I finally "draw" the point cloud in, I get this:
[image]

It's purple, and it says "missing vertex normals".

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems scalar fields are not correctly imported with the PCV addon. I personally use cloudcompare (free software) to load the ply, select it, go to edit > Color > From Scalar fields and export the ply again. This will populate the rgb fields