# Meshlab import to Blender

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to export 3D scans from Meshlab to Blender but when importing to Blender the scans lose their colour.

I have tried to export as .ply file but still no colour.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36783/import-ply-doesnt-display-vertex-colors/36859#36859 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158052/blender-2-81-doesnt-seem-to-be-importing-vertex-color-for-ply

Comment: @brockmann I tried to export as .ply file and still no colour, it could be an issue with exporting from mesh lab instead of importing to blender, I'm not too sure, do you know how to make sure texture/colour is exported correctly from mesh lab?