# Access material node drivers from python

Tags: python, scripting, materials, node-editor, drivers

I would like to store my whole node input driver set up of a material in a txt file and load it back any time. How can I access the driver data along with node name and input number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look in `NodeTree.animation_data`**

Python console code.  Loop thru materials that use nodes and have animation data, if so loop the drivers collection.

[image]

In simple example below find the couple of simple drivers including a  driver on a value node with expression "frame" (*the current frame*)

The drivers datapath gives the node name and the index of the socket.

```
>>> for m in bpy.data.materials:
...     m.name
...     if m.use_nodes and m.node_tree.animation_data:
...         for d in m.node_tree.animation_data.drivers:
...             d.data_path, d.driver.expression
...             
'Material'
('nodes["Value"].outputs[0].default_value', 'frame')
('nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[9].default_value', 'frame / 20')

>>>
```

Re socket index and name https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160069/15543