# Wave texture change values by python code

Tags: materials, objects

I'm trying to change the values of Wave Texture (Shader Editor) by python:
I mean that I what to change the value of Distortion or Detail Scale by python code.

```
wave_texture = bpy.data.objects['plane'].active_material.node_tree.nodes['Wave Texture']
```

I stack at this point, how I get and set Distortion for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a node input sockets by either their name or their rank using their `inputs` property:

```
distortion_socket = wave_texture.inputs['Distortion']
```

or

```
distortion_socket = wave_texture.inputs[2]
```

Then you can set the value using `default_value` (the value not given by a link):

```
distortion_socket.default_value = 2
```

Comment: Using the index (rank) is fail-safe in case user is  using another language.  Console is a  handy way to enumerate them https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160069/15543