# How to show the edge color from imported '.ply' file?

Tags: edges, color

I have a ply file `new.ply`.

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 8
property float x
property float y
property float z
element face 7
property list uchar int vertex_index
element edge 5 
property int vertex1 
property int vertex2 
property uchar red 
property uchar green
property uchar blue 
end_header
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 1 1 
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
3 0 1 2 
3 0 2 3 
4 7 6 5 4
4 0 4 5 1
4 1 5 6 2
4 2 6 7 3
4 3 7 4 0
0 1 255 0 255
1 2 255 255 0
2 3 0 255 255
3 0 255 255 255
2 0 0 0 0
```

Can I show the edge color in Blender?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a complete solution, but I hope it will help you plan your next steps.
First read this: [File format with per face colors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30314/file-format-with-per-face-colors?rq=1)
Blender isn't importing any colors from your .ply, so either it's a shortcoming in Blender, or the file isn't properly formated.
Once you managed to get the colors, use the material setup below. Where mine says "Col" your setup will be empty at the beginning, if you click on the empty field, there should be only one option, if there are none, the color import failed.
For triangulated view, you can use this setup:
[image]
Important: This only works with triangles!
If you want to show polygons > 3 vertices, use the Wireframe Modifier and delete the Wireframe and the Multiply node from the setup. The Wireframe Modifier can be used on top of your old geometry, to show both.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am puzzled that the ply file contains the color properties but it seems hard to visualization.  Do you know any other tool that can implement this?