# Python: Create Polyline and Polyloop

Tags: python, modeling

How to create polyline and then poly loop with python.
Bmesh fastest way.

Here is an example:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: How about creating bm.verts, then connect them with bm.edges and finally extrude via bmesh.ops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a polyline. (btw, imposing pure bmesh requirements on this is probably arbitrary, and using [from_pydata](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2408/47) is just as good)

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

scene = bpy.context.scene 
meshes = bpy.data.meshes
objects = bpy.data.objects

# generate polyline 

bm = bmesh.new()
verts = [bm.verts.new((0, 0, z)) for z in range(5)]

for i in range(len(verts)-1):
    bm.edges.new([verts[i], verts[i+1]])

me = meshes.new('placeholder_mesh')
mesh_obj = objects.new('polyline', me)

scene.objects.link(mesh_obj)

bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()
```

Run this on a polyline:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

bmesh.ops.extrude_edge_only(bm, edges=bm.edges[:])
bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=Vector((0,1.2,0)), verts=[v for v in bm.verts if v.select])

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

See TextEditor -> Templates -> Python -> Simple Bmesh (edit mode) for the templates.

---

It might just be simpler to construct the polygon loop from scratch using from_pydata. It really depends on the final use-case

Comment: How to make polygon loop from scratch using from_pydata?

Comment: see first sentence in my answer. ( http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/how-to-create-a-mesh-programmatically-without-bmesh/2408#2408 ) all you need are the vertex coordinates and the face index loops, building from scratch you are responsible for that.

Comment: i think this is not what i need. I use editmode only. Could you check this issue too? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31733/python-fix-normal-of-a-new-polygon

Comment: yeah, from_pydata isn't designed for interactive / edit mode mesh updates.  I already looked at your other post, interesting problem.