# How to use loops.foreach_set and polygons.foreach_set to add faces to a mesh

Tags: python, scripting

I have problems getting my head around it:

I have two arrays:

```
verts = np.array([1, 1, 0,
                  2, 1, 0, 
                  3, 1, 0, 
                  1, 2, 0, 
                  2, 2, 0, 
                  3, 2, 0, 
                  1, 3, 0, 
                  2, 3, 0, 
                  3, 3, 0])

faces = np.array([0, 1, 4, 3,
                  1, 2, 5, 4, 
                  3, 4, 7, 6, 
                  4, 5, 8, 7])
```

The mesh (me) is prepared with the 9 verts from array "verts" in it already. Now i want to add the faces but the explanations i found were scarce at best.

So, how do i add faces using (an explanation would be great):

```
    me.loops.add() #should be 4 loops per (4-sided) face, right?
    me.loops.foreach_set("vertex_index",) #no idea...

    me.polygons.add(faces.size / 4) #4 Faces in this case
    me.polygons.foreach_set("loop_start",) #no idea... 
    me.polygons.foreach_set("loop_total",) #not sure... number of loops per face in a list: [4, 4, 4, 4] in this case?
    #me.polygons.foreach_set("vertices", ) #needed at all? List of vert coordinates if they were no verts in mesh already?
```

I would be very happy if anybody could shed some light on it for me.

**EDIT**
After some investigation of "from_pydata" code in "bpy_types.py" as suggested by batFINGER i am a bit further but still not fully able to create the correct mesh.
I now have most of it right i think but because i have shared vertices for some of the loops and edges i am now pretty sure I need to use:

```
me.loops.foreach_set("vertex_index", vert_idx)
```

i thought i would need to add two verts per loop (start and end), so:

```
vert_idx = (0, 1, 
            1, 4, 
            4, 3, 
            3, 0, 
            1, 2, 
            2, 5, 
            5, 4, 
            4, 1, 
            3, 4, 
            4, 7, 
            7, 6, 
            6, 3, 
            4, 5, 
            5, 8, 
            8, 7, 
            7, 4)
```

or "faces" but both leads to a crash, like everything else i tried.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/how-to-create-a-mesh-programmatically-without-bmesh)  You really want to use `Mesh.from_pydata(...)` or a bmesh approach.  Consider foreach get and set more a way to get or set property data to / from a flat list, rather than as a way to create meshes.

Comment: "You really want to use Mesh.from_pydata(...)"  I do not.

Comment: Fair enough, change _"you really want to use"_ to _"I strongly suggest using"_

Comment: Sounds better ;)... i need as much speed as possible creating large meshes (data created with numpy) and "foreach_set" method should be much faster (but i will not find out if i cannot get it running) ...

Comment: The code for `from_pydata` is in `bpy_types.py` as [mentioned here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2416/15543)

Comment: Looked into it, thx, that should help to maybe figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, what was missing was not:

```
me.loops.foreach_set("vertex_index", vert_idx)
```

but correct:

```
me.polygons.foreach_set("vertices", ...
```

i tried it before and it crashed all the time because i forgot to ravel() the numpy array i used.